# Python. Collect data until the end of json file

Tags: python, json, api

```
binance_prices = {}

def get_binance_price():
    Prices = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price"
    r = requests.get(url=Prices)
    data = r.json()
    for coin in range(0,375):
        binance_prices.update( { data[coin]["symbol"]: data[coin]["price"]} )
```

I'm trying to get all coin prices from Binance and the code above works fine, but the problem is that if they will add a new coin, I won't catch it. So I thought about changing `for coin in range(0,375):` for

```
counter = 0
    while True:
        counter = counter + 1
        binance_prices.update( { data[counter]["symbol"]: data[counter]["price"]} )
```

but how do I leave the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't do this at all. You'd iterate through the data, not an arbitrary number.

```
for coin in data:
    binance_prices.update( { coin["symbol"]: coin["price"]} )
```

It's an important principle in Python that you always iterate directly over a collection, rather than using `range` and an index.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot